# BlockingCollection<T> in a BackgroundService causes high CPU usage

Tags: c#, blockingcollection, .net-6.0, worker-service

I have a .NET `BackgroundService` for managing notifications by using a `BlockingCollection<Notification>`.

My implementation is cause high CPU usage, even though there is not that much work to be handled by the `BlockingCollection`.

I've collected some dumps and it seems that I am running into thread pool starvation.

I am not sure how this should be refactor to avoid this situation.

```
private readonly BlockingCollection<Notification> _notifications;

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await _notificationsContext.Database.MigrateAsync(stoppingToken);

            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {

                foreach (var notification in _notifications.GetConsumingEnumerable(stoppingToken))
                {
                   // process notification
                }


            }
        }, stoppingToken);
    }
```

I've also tried to remove the while loop but the issue still persists.

[image: core dump screenshot]

EDIT: Added the producer

```
 public abstract class CommandHandlerBase
    {
        private readonly BlockingCollection<Notification> _notifications;

        public CommandHandlerBase(BlockingCollection<Notification> notifications)
        {
            _notifications = notifications;
        }
        protected void EnqueueNotification(AlertImapact alertImapact,
                                           AlertUrgency alertUrgency,
                                           AlertSeverity alertServerity,
                                           string accountName,
                                           string summary,
                                           string details,
                                           bool isEnabled,
                                           Exception exception,
                                           CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {

            var notification = new Notification(accountName, summary, details, DateTime.UtcNow, exception.GetType().ToString())
            {
                Imapact = alertImapact,
                Urgency = alertUrgency,
                Severity = alertServerity,
                IsSilenced = !isEnabled,
            };

            _notifications.Add(notification, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'd start with removing `Task.Run(async () => ` part completely. While loop is also not needed but it doesn't do anything anyway.

Comment: Your error message shows you're blocking thread pool threads on that `GetConsumingEnumerable` call, which is blocking. If that's causing thread pool starvation, I assume you must be calling `ExecuteAsync` many times in parallel? Stealing 1 thread pool thread forever is bad (it's not what the thread pool is for), but to cause starvation you must be blocking many thread pool threads.

Comment: ExecuteAsync should return a task that represents the lifetime of the background service, so atleast await your Task.Run if you must use it..

Comment: I am not calling `ExecuteAsync `  at all, I am using a .NET worker service, the runtime is starting it. I also tried it by removing the `Task.Run()` call, but still no improvement.

Comment: Why not put some logging / a breakpoint in there, to see how many times it's being called?

Comment: @Mihaimyh it would be a far better idea to use Channels instead of BlockingCollection. With a channel you can not only await to receive, you can receive messages through an `IAsyncEnumerable` using `ChannelReader.ReadAllAsync`

Comment: You've shown us the consumer of the `_notifications`. Where is the producer?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I've added now the producer, it's an abstract class calling the `Add` method on the `BlockingCollection`.

Comment: Mihaimyh are you creating multiple instances of the abstract producer class, that are adding notifications in parallel, or just one instance? Also how many notifications are added per second on average?

Comment: I found the problem, it was not related to this part of the code, but rather to another `BackgroundService` which had a `Task.Delay()` with a wrongly calculated `Time.Span` causing the thread pool starvation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blocking is expensive but putting the thread to sleep and rescheduling is even more expensive. To avoid this .NET typically starts blocking operations with a [SpinWait](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/spinwait) before actually blocking the thread. A spinwait uses a core to do nothing for a while, which causes the CPU usage you  observed.

To fix this, use an asynchronous collection like [Channels](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/an-introduction-to-system-threading-channels/).

- A channel allows you to asynchronously post or read messages to it, preserving their order.
- It's thread safe which means multiple readers and writers can write to it at the same time.
- You can create a bounded channel to prevent publishers to post if a channel is full.
- Finally, you can read all messages in a Channel through an `IAsyncEnumerable`, making the processing code easier.

**Avoid blocking with Channels**

In your case, the code could change to this:

```
private readonly Channel<Notification> _notifications=Channel.CreateUnbounded<Notification>();

protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    await _notificationsContext.Database.MigrateAsync(stoppingToken);

    await foreach(var notification in _notifications.Reader.ReadAllAsync(stoppingToken))
    {
               // process notification
    }
}
```

Channels intentionally use separate interfaces for reading and writing. To Read, you use the [ChannelReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channelreader-1?view=net-5.0) class returned by [Channel.Reader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channel-2.reader?view=net-5.0). To write, you use the [ChannelWriter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channelwriter-1?view=net-5.0) class returned by [Channel.Writer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channel-2.writer?view=net-5.0). A Channel can be [implicitly cast](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channel-2.op_implicit?view=net-5.0) to either type, making it easy to write publisher and subscriber methods that only accept/produce a ChannelReader or ChannelWriter.

To write to the channel you use ChannelWriter's [WriteAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channelwriter-1.writeasync?view=net-5.0) method:

```
await _notifications.Writer.WriteAsync(someNotification);
```

When you're done writing and want to close the channel, you need to call [Complete()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channelwriter-1.complete?view=net-5.0) on the writer:

```
await _notification.Writer.Complete();
```

The processing loop will read any remaining messages. To await until it finishes you need to await the [ChannelReader.Completion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channelreader-1.completion?view=net-5.0) task:

```
await _notification.Reader.Completion;
```

**Posting from other classes**

When you work with a BackgroundService notifications will typically arrive from other classes. This means that somehow both the publisher and the service need access to the same Channel. One way to do this is to use a helper class and inject it both in the publisher and service.

The `MessageChannel<T>` class does this and also handles application termination by closing the writer:

```
public class MessageChannel<T>:IDisposable 
    {
        private readonly Channel<Envelope<T>> _channel;

        public ChannelReader<Envelope<T>> Reader => _channel;
        public ChannelWriter<Envelope<T>> Writer => _channel;

        public MessageChannel(IHostApplicationLifetime lifetime)
        {
            _channel = Channel.CreateBounded<Envelope<T>>(1);
            lifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(() => Writer.TryComplete());
        }

        private readonly CancellationTokenSource _cts = new();

        public CancellationToken CancellationToken => _cts.Token;
        public void Stop()
        {
            _cts.Cancel();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _cts.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

This can be injected in the background service:

```
MessageChannel<Notification> _notifications;
ChannelReader<Notification> _reader;

public MyService(MessageChannel<Notification> notifications)
{
    _notifications=notifications;
    _reader=notifications.Reader;
}

protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    await _notificationsContext.Database.MigrateAsync(stoppingToken);

    await foreach(var notification in _reader.ReadAllAsync(stoppingToken))
    {
               // process notification
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, although I found out that my problem was related to another part of the code, I will accept your solution since it seems to be a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that the problem was related to another `BackgroundService` which was waiting on a wrongly calculated `TimeSpan` causing thread pool starvation.

Answer (score -3):

While I think there can be arguments towards the proposed channel solution, like proposed earlier, I would vote for a more simple solution, the channels are intended for a high volume of messages if You will, so do consider it if there are very many messages.

I Suspect your high CPU happen because your notification queue is empty and You have no waits.

```
    public class Worker : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly ConcurrentQueue _messages = new ConcurrentQueue();               

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    await _notificationsContext.Database.MigrateAsync(stoppingToken);
                    while (_messages.TryDequeue(out var notification) && !stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        //ProcessNotificaiton      
                    }
                    
                    //Explicit delay for the cases when you have no notification you do not want to enter frantic looping which is what i suspect is happening
                   Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```